# XNA Erase/Remove a Texture2D

Tags: xna

i'm new to XNA 4.0 and i want to create a space ship shooter game. When i kill the enemy i want to draw a explode texture where it death and the explode texture will disappear for 2 seconds. I managed to draw a explode texture when enemy died by using boolean if enemy is die or not in Draw method but i don't know how to remove it after 2 seconds. Thank you for your help.

```
if (alive)
sp.Draw(enemyTexture, enemyPos, Color.White);

else
sp.Draw(explode, enemyPos, Color.White);
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a similar check for two second interval between the start of the explosion and its end. You could just save the time of explosion and check if it is 2 seconds or more older than the current time, like so:

```
TimeSpan explosionTime;
if (itsTimeToExplode)
    explosionTime = gameTime.TotalGameTime;
```

Then you make a check to see if it is time to remove the explosion animation:

```
if (gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds - explosionTime.TotalMilliseconds >= 2000) // 2000 milliseconds is 2 seconds
    RemoveExplosionAnimation();
```

You can put the `explosionTime` inside your enemy class and only delete the enemy after it's dead and the explosion animation has been played.

Answer (score 0):

You need to count the time inside Update method using gameTime variable.
When your counter reaches 2s, just make alive = false;
But better idea is to make class for your explosion sprite with update and draw methods
and handle the counting and rendering from there.